# Find percentage of increase between two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am building that requires multiple flags. One of those flags is to find the percentage of increase between two values in the same row.

For example I have two values on my row:

```
Col1 26323 &
Col2 26397
```

Col2 has increased by 0.28 % on Col1. How can I express this in my query?

Comment: Hint:  `100 * ((col2 / col1) - 1)`.

Comment: You can write an equation in SQL Server for a column. To get the value of a percentage of something, you divide one by the other: `value2 / value1 = Percentage`; i.e. `20 / 100 = 0.2 = 20%`. have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: watch out for SQL integer arithmetic taking over if col1 & col2 are integers SELECT (CAST(col2 as float) / CAST(col1 as float) - 1) * 100.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  
    100.0*(col1 - col2) / col2 As pdif
FROM ptable
```

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input, this is the one that worked best for me.

Answer (score 2):

In this way

```
select Col1, Col2, (Col2 *100.0/Col1)-100 from (
select Col1 = 26323 , Col2 =26397
)a
```

Result :

```
Col1    Col2    (No column name)
26323   26397   0.281122972305
```